# Why does Perl's "system ('some command')" behave differently from c:\> some command?

Tags: perl, cmd, spawn

In my (cmd.exe's) current working directory is a file named *libre-office-document.odt*. I can open this document using the `start` command without problem:

```
c:\path\to\> start libre-office-document.odt
```

Yet, if I use the following simple Perl script

```
use warnings;
use strict;

print system("start libre-office-document.odt")
```

and execute it in the same directory, I get the following message box:

> **LibreOffice 4.4 - Fatal Error**
>
> The application cannot be started.
>   User installation could not be completed.

Obviously, something behaves differently when using Perl's `system` command. I am unable to determine what that is and how I can open the document with the `system` command.

Comment: One reason can be that Environment variables are missing

Comment: But do not Environment variables get propagated to the spawned process? It's my understanding that Windows does not have *exported* vs *non exported* variables as in a Unix shell.

Comment: If you have admin privilege can you try starting cmd prompt as admin and retry.

Comment: instead you can use "call" method

Comment: I'd guess that tries to execute a binary called `start[.exe]`. Try `system( qq{cmd /c "start libre-office-document.odt"});`. But it's only a guess.

Comment: Did you execute the Perl program from a console?

Comment: Yes, from the very same cmd.exe prompt that succeeded with the start command.

Comment: @PerlDog your suggestion resulted in the same message box.

Comment: The dialogue box shows that it comes from LibreOffice 4.4. That means the application has successfully started. I would guess that there is something in the startup of LibreOffice to which the child process doesn't have access. You need to look through the event log to see exactly what process died and why

Comment: IIRC Window's "start" command behaves a bit strangely in scripts.  Try wrapping your line in a batch/cmd file for another comparison (completely outside perl.exe).

Comment: print system command return the command state,forexample if you run `print system("ls")` you get 0 + result of the ls.so tried to just execute `system("start libre-office-document.odt")` or if u want the result of the command execute in system place start libre-office-document.odt in ``(backtick).example my $res = system `start libre-office-document.odt`;

Comment: Maybe the difference is that perl exits after the command is started whereas the console stays open? You can add a sleep(5) to your script to test this or omit "start " from the command so that perl waits for the started command to finish execution.

Comment: was this ever solved? if not, I have some suggestions that can perhaps solve it.

Comment: Have you tried using `START /D` to force the started process to also initiate from the current directory?  Perl's `system()` may default to the user's login directory.

Comment: system() does some extra processing when there is only one argument. You might want to try "system(qw(start libre-office-document.odt));" where two arguments are used.

Answer (score 1):

Use backticks to capture  output.
You can check file associations with assoc and ftype, than hardcode it, or try this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $assoc = `assoc .odt`;

# .odt=LibreOffice.WriterDocument.1
chomp $assoc;

$assoc =~ s/.*=//g;

my $ftype = `ftype $assoc`;

# LibreOffice.WriterDocument.1="C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe" -o "%1"
chomp $ftype;

$ftype =~ /.*=("[^"]*")/;
$ftype = $1;

# "C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.exe" libre-office-document.odt    
my $cmd = "$ftype libre-office-document.odt";

system($cmd);
```